# Failing to connect RabbitMQ through a EasyNetQ, getting access refused for user guest

Tags: c#, linux, windows, rabbitmq, easynetq

Getting a strange error that doesn't make sense to me.

RabbitMQ is refusing to allow access from a .Net application using EasyNetQ on a particular machine, when it works fine on another machine.

The client app clearly resolves DNS, permissions are wide open, and it works in another situation.

This is an out of the box rabbitmq installation.

RabbitMQ is running on a Linux Amazon Instance, while the client is running on a Windows Server 2008 Amazon instance, and it works from a Windows 8 desktop.

I am getting:

=ERROR REPORT==== 2-Jul-2013::11:54:04 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.1145.22> (107.23.30.43:62815 -> 10.125.160.196:5672):
{handshake_error,opening,0,
                 {amqp_error,access_refused,
                             "access to vhost '/\r\n          ' refused for user 'guest'",
                             'connection.open'}}

Any ideas?

Thanks,

- Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, `'/\r\n'` should be just `'/'`, unless you explicitly create such vhost with special symbols in name. Check your connection params.

Comment: Figured it out already, but that was indeed part of the answer.