# JS webstomp BAD CONNECT Access refused for user 'guest'

Tags: javascript, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

I have problem with connection to RabbitMQ server (version: 3.8.2, erlang version: 22.2.8) by JS (on browser) webstomp. I'm using **stomp.js**.

I'm using example from here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-web-stomp-examples/blob/master/priv/echo.html

I've done everything like is described here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/web-stomp.html

I've set permissions to my user using this: `sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / user ".*" ".*" ".*"`

I've set tags to my user using this: `sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags user management`

I've already checked these solutions:
[Failing to connect RabbitMQ through a EasyNetQ, getting access refused for user guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430965/failing-to-connect-rabbitmq-through-a-easynetq-getting-access-refused-for-user) and 
[RabbitMQ - access to vhost 'XXX' refused for user 'guest'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51195026/rabbitmq-access-to-vhost-xxx-refused-for-user-guest),
and others that I found in google.

My configuration for `rabbitmq_web_stomp`:

```
{rabbitmq_web_stomp,
      [
       {tcp_config, [{port, 15674}
                    ]
       },
       {use_http_auth, true},
       {ssl_config, [{port,       15673},
                     {backlog,    1024},
                     {cacertfile,"path/to/cert"},
                     {certfile,"path/to/cert"},
                     {keyfile,"path/to/cert"},
                     {password,  "pass"}
                    ]
      }
     ]
  },
```

I always get the same response from server:

```
Opening Web Socket...
Web Socket Opened...
>>> CONNECT login:user passcode:pass host:/ accept-version:1.1,1.0 heart-beat:10000,10000 
<<< ERROR message:Bad CONNECT content-type:text/plain version:1.0,1.1,1.2 content-length:32 Access refused for user 'guest' 
Whoops! Lost connection to ws://ip.addres/ws
```

I have access (for this user) to the server by .NET Core client in C# and by **Management Plugin**

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
I don't exactly sure why it works but it was enough to remove the `{use_http_auth, true}` from configuration. After that there was no problem with connection from JS from browser.